# Adding functions to javascript's array in a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm try to creat array with functions in a loop. But I think don't get something about encapsulation.

For example this code returns "y y". [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kXe5y/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var json = {
            '1':'x',
            '2':'y'
           };
var my_array = [];
var div = document.getElementById('result');

for (var key in json) {
    my_array.push(function() { 
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + ' ' + json[key];
    });
};

var length = my_array.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  my_function = my_array[i];
  my_function();
}
```

What should I do to get "x y"?

Tnx a lot.

Comment: Another case of bitten by closure

Comment: it does not work, because at the time u you calling the function the value of key variable is '2'

Comment: @KamenStoykov, oh i know why it doesn't work :)

Comment: Just a bit of curiosity here. Why do you need to have an array of functions? Isn't it even simpler to have an array of keys or whatever values that need to be used?

Comment: @Frederik.L I'm making waterfall with ajax requests

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the way closures work in JavaScript.

You want something like this:

```
for (var key in json) {
    (function(key) {
        my_array.push(function() { 
            div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + ' ' + json[key];
        });
    })(key);
}
```

In JavaScript, closures or anonymous functions are lexically bound to the scope in which they are defined. What this means is that they have access to all variables that have been defined in the scope in which the closure is *also* defined.

So in your original code, you have `key`, which initially points to `1`. In your function, you have `json[key]`, which originally is `json[1]`, which is `x`. Then when the loop goes to the next iteration you have `key` set to `2`. But the thing is that `key` in the first function instance and the second function instance *both point to the same location*. So when you finally evaluate the function, they will use whatever value `key` has *at the time of execution*. At the time of execution, `key` is set to `2` because that was the last value of `key` at the end of the loop.

To fix this, you have to introduce a new scope by using an anonymous, self-invoked function. By using this pattern, you deliberately introduce a *new* scope such that `key` in this new scope has its own location and is different from `key` in the outer scope.

[Check out the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kXe5y/1/).

Comment: This doesn't work... Even if you can identify the problem, you might want to verify that your code works before submitting it as an answer

Comment: @taylorc93 Minor typo; fixed.

Comment: You don't "**have to** introduce a new scope by using an anonymous, self-invoked function". You can do it in a cleaner way by calling a function that passes the necessary things and returns a new function/scope.

Comment: @Ian That is another approach that would work as well. I guess it's a matter of personal preference, but I find it much more idiomatic to use an anonymous function in this manner rather than calling another function. You then have to jump to that function which can be a little jarring and cause some loss of context. Again, just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @VivinPaliath thx a lot. Works fine. Special thanks for the comments