# jQuery hide() when JS loop finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JS loop:

```
          for (var i = 0; i < jsArr.length; ++i) {
            $.post("checkdata.php", { names: jsArr[i], platforms: "1" })
            .done(function(data) {
                eval(data);
            });
          }
```

`data` is some jQuery CSS manipulation. I have a loading image that is under the "loadingImg" div class which is display on page load. `checkdata.php` checks the `names` against the API https://www.xboxleaders.com/

What's the best way to accomplish `$('#loadingImg').hide();` (to hide the image) after the loop and the jQuery `.done` processes complete?

I have thought about adding it after the loop, but that does not guarantee `checkdata` has finished.

Comment: Do you really need all those Ajax calls? can't you send all data at once?

Comment: Perform your `.hide` as part of your `.done` callback. You'll need to track whether you're on the last iteration. Of course, if you can send ll the data at once (thanks @koala_dev) then there are fewer calls, faster response, and no tracking to consider

Comment: You can just send for example `namesArr : jsArr` and send data for all images not only for one.

Comment: The first thing you should do, is remove that `eval()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter:

```
      var counter = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < jsArr.length; ++i) {
        $.post("checkdata.php", { names: jsArr[i], platforms: "1" })
        .done(function(data) {
            counter++;
            eval(data);
            if(counter == jsArr.length){
                $('#loadingImg').hide();
            }
        });
      }
```

Comment: or use i as smerny suggested, even better

Answer (score 3):

$.when can be used to combine deferreds, and will resolve, when all of them are resolved.

```
var defs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < jsArr.length; ++i) {
  defs.unshift($.post("checkdata.php", { names: jsArr[i], platforms: "1" }));
  defs[0].done(function(data) {
    eval(data);
  });
}

$.when.apply($, defs).done(function() {
  $('#loadingImg').hide();
});
```

Comment: +1 looks about right, hard to test, but putting the deferreds in an array and calling $.when is the way to go.

Comment: I also haven't tested it, so take it with a grain of salt

Answer (score 0):

You better use [waterfall](https://github.com/dio-el-claire/jquery.waterfall)

[This question would be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603267/adding-functions-to-javascripts-array-in-a-loop).

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this is by creating a second array that has the same number of elements as jsArr.  On each .done, set the corresponding index of the second array to true.  Then in each call of .done, check if all the values of the second array are true, and if so, hide.  (Or you could just push a new value into the second array and check if the length of the arrays are the same for the hide to take effect)

```
doneChecks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < jsArr.length; ++i) {
    $.post("checkdata.php", { names: jsArr[i], platforms: "1" })
        .done(function(data) {
            doneChecks.push(true);
            eval(data);
            if (doneChecks.length == jsArr.length)
                $('#loadingImg').hide(); 
    });
}
```